# Which row is returned using DISTINCT ON in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, distinct-on

When I use `DISTINCT ON` in PostgreSQL (distinct in django) which rows are retrieved in the group of rows with same fields?

Comment: the one that comes at first

Comment: The first value

Comment: Distinct doesn't delete anything

Comment: @Sayse by delete I mean which row is retrieved ?

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT) says:

> A set of rows for which all the expressions are equal are considered
>   duplicates, and only the first row of the set is kept in the output.
>   Note that the "first row" of a set is unpredictable unless the query
>   is sorted on enough columns to guarantee a unique ordering of the
>   rows arriving at the `DISTINCT` filter.

So if you add an `ORDER BY` clause, the first row in that order is kept.

Without an `ORDER BY` clause, there is no way of telling which row will be kept.

Comment: yes, i tried some but each time the result is changed. need order to get static result.